# ajax with jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: ajax

I have created an autosuggestion list using jquery and WordPress function. My autosuggestion working fine. I am giving my code here

> Jquery Code

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#my_ajax').autocomplete({
        // minChars: 1,
        source: function(request, response) {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: devel_ajax.ajaxurl,
            data: 'action=my_ajax'+'&name='+request.term,
            success: function(data) {

              response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                  return {
                      label: item.title,
                      value: item.title
                  }
              }));

            }
          });
        },
        minLength: 3,


  });

 })(jQuery);
```

> PHP Code

```
function user_autocomplete($value){
      global $wpdb;
      $name = $wpdb->esc_like(stripslashes($value));
      $users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT
        $wpdb->users.ID
        FROM $wpdb->users
         WHERE LOWER($wpdb->users.user_login) LIKE LOWER('".$name."%')");
        $autocomplete = array();
        foreach($users as $key => $user){
          $user_info = get_userdata($user->ID);
          $firstname = $user_info->first_name;
          $lastname = $user_info->last_name;
        if(!empty($firstname) || !empty($lastname)){
          $username = ucfirst($firstname) . ' '. ucfirst($lastname);
        }else{
          $username = $user_info->user_login;
        }
        $email = $user_info->user_login; 
        $website = $user_info->website; 
        $autocomplete[$user->ID] = array(
        'ID' => $user->ID,
        'Name'    => $username
        'email'    => $email
        'website'    => $website
        );
    }
    return $autocomplete;
  }
```

> HTML Code

```
<form action='' method='POST' role="form" class="bottom-space">
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="my_ajax" autofocus="" value="" type="text" name="q" placeholder="my_ajax" style="width:100%;max-width:600px;outline:0" autocomplete="off">
  <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="hidden" value=''>
  <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="hidden" value=''>
  <input id="id" name="user_id" type="hidden" value=''>
  <input id="email" name="email" type="hidden" value=''>
  <input id="website" name="email" type="hidden" value=''>
</div>
<submit type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit
  Button</submit>

</form>
```

But the problem is I can not set others hidden input Field. Any kind of help or suggestions highly appreciable.

Comment: maybe http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response will help you

Comment: this is really a JS question, not a wordpress one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is not tested. But I think this should be work for you. I am giving you some code snippet.

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#my_ajax').autocomplete({
        // minChars: 1,
        source: function(request, response) {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: devel_ajax.ajaxurl,
            data: 'action=my_ajax'+'&name='+request.term,
            success: function(data) {
              response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                  var object = new Object();
                  object.label = item.Name;
                  object.value = item.Name;
                  object.ID = item.ID;
                  object.email = item.email;
                  object.website = item.website;
                  return object
              }));
              // response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
              //     return {
              //         label: item.title,
              //         value: item.title
              //     }
              // }));

            }
          });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
          $("#my_ajax").val(ui.item.value);
          $("#firstname").val(ui.item.value);
          $("#id").val(ui.item.ID);
          $("#email").val(ui.item.email);
          $("#website").val(ui.item.website);
         }
      });

  });

 })(jQuery);
```